# Comparing hostname part of authenticated_id to sender_address in exim

Tags: exim

currently my acl check_mail part looks like this:

```
deny  
    message = The sender name must be the same as the login id  
    condition = ${if eq{$sender_address}{$authenticated_id}{no}{yes}}
```

However I would like to verify the domain only.
How do I strip that part out of the variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `domain:` operator:

```
deny
    message = The sender name must be the same as the login id
    condition = ${if eq{${domain:$sender_address}}{${domain:$authenticated_id}}{no}{yes}}
```

In case it's not clear, after adding `domain:` the variable `$sender_address` becomes `${domain:$sender_address}`.  The only real problem is that if the variable wasn't in the form of an email to begin with, it will expand to an empty string.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! It's also described on http://exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch11.html. But the docs can be quite challenging to work through. (Don't have enough rep to upvote you, sry)